# Exporting or creating a database, which is quicker?

Tags: mysql, database, import, export

Which one is quicker, exporting and importing a database, or creating a database from scratch with all the tables and views.

Assuming that the tables are empty and that you have 7-15 tables/views. Also the entire thing is done by code.

Also Does it differ based on whether you are using MSSQL, MySQL etc.?

Answer (score 0):

For **MySQL** fastest way to move a DB from one place to another is to do a binary copy. Just taking the /var/lib/mysql/**databasename**/ (location may vary) from one server to another and restarting **MySQL** on that new server is enough to move the data to that new server.

I have no idea about MSSQL.

Comment: Could you explain how to take the value? I'm not familiar with this. Thanks